# Bokeh on_click function changes text only after entire function has completed

Tags: python, bokeh

On Python 3.7 with Bokeh 1.4.0, I am noticing that when I use a button to run a function that changes the text on the page and then run some code, the text does not change until the entire function has finished running. Here is an example where you would expect the text to change instantly, but it does not change until the time.sleep() has completed. Here is an example snippet I am launching from a jupyter notebook:

```
import time
from bokeh.models.widgets import Div
from bokeh.layouts import layout
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button
from bokeh.server.server import Server
from bokeh.application import Application
from bokeh.application.handlers.function import FunctionHandler

def make_document(doc):
    bokeh_text=Div(text="")
    test_button=Button(label='TEST',button_type="success")
    def test():
        bokeh_text.text = "Text has been changed"        
        time.sleep(3)
    test_button.on_click(test)
    my_layout=layout([test_button,bokeh_text])
    doc.add_root(my_layout)

import numpy as np
apps = {'/': Application(FunctionHandler(make_document))}
server = Server(apps)
server.io_loop.add_callback(server.show, "/")
```

[Here it is with time.sleep(3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKcUu.gif)

[Here is it without time.sleep()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkfyk.gif)

Comment: probably all GUIs work like that - they don't update window at once but when code returns to mainloop - and then it has to redraw window only once for all changes - so it has less work to do and window doesn't flickering. In desktop GUIs you could use some function to force mainloop to redraw window but I don't know if bokeh has function for this.

Answer (score 1):

Probably all GUIs work like that - they don't update window at once but when code returns to mainloop - and then it has to redraw window only once for all changes - so it has less work to do and window doesn't flickering.

In desktop GUIs you could use some function to force mainloop to redraw window. Or you can use timer to run calculations with small delay so code can go back to mainloop which updates window and starts calculation

I don't know if bokeh has function to force update but it has function to run code with delay

```
def test():
    bokeh_text.text = "Text has been changed"     
    doc.add_next_tick_callback(job)
    #doc.add_timeout_callback(job, 10) 
    # now it can go back to mainloop to update window and later mainloop will run `job` 

def job():
    time.sleep(3)
    bokeh_text.text = "End of test"
```

But it is not so useful if you want to update text many times during long running calculations. Probably you would have to run it in separated thread and use queue to send information to main thread which could use `add_periodic_callback()` to periodically check queue and update text on page.

---

Doc: [bokeh.document](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/document.html) - see `add_next_tick_callback()`, `add_timeout_callback()` and `add_periodic_callback()`

---

**EDIT:** Example using Thread for this

```
import time
from bokeh.models.widgets import Div
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button
from bokeh.layouts import layout
from bokeh.server.server import Server
from bokeh.application import Application
from bokeh.application.handlers.function import FunctionHandler
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue

callback_id = None # global variable so it can be used in `test` and `update_text`
t = None           # global variable so it can be used in `test` and `update_text`

def make_document(doc):
    bokeh_text = Div(text="")
    test_button = Button(label='TEST', button_type="success")

    def test():
        #global callback_id
        global t        

        if t is not None:
            print("already running")
        else:
            q = Queue()
            t = Thread(target=job, args=(q,)) # send queue to job - it has to be `,` in `(q,)` to create tuple with one element
            t.start()
            callback_id = doc.add_periodic_callback(lambda:update_text(q), 100)

    def job(queue):
        queue.put("Start")
        for x in range(10):
            time.sleep(1)
            queue.put(str(x))
        time.sleep(1)
        queue.put("End")

    def update_text(queue):
        #global callback_id
        global t

        if not queue.empty():
            value = queue.get()
            bokeh_text.text = value
            #if not t.is_alive():
            if value == 'End': # and callback_id is not None:
                doc.remove_periodic_callback(callback_id)
                #callback_id = None
                print("callback removed")
                t = None # to inform `test()` that it can run thread again

    test_button.on_click(test)
    my_layout = layout([test_button, bokeh_text])
    doc.add_root(my_layout)

apps = {'/': Application(FunctionHandler(make_document))}
server = Server(apps, port=8888)
server.io_loop.add_callback(server.show, "/")
server.io_loop.start()
#server.run_until_shutdown()
```